# Case statement equivalent as an SSRS expressions

Tags: reporting-services, expression

How could I go about writing the case statement as an SSRS expression so I don't have to modify the SQL source code? I don't understand how to call the field if the conditions are not met,

```
case when  [Location Type] = 'COMMER' and [Contract] = '2)FRA Components' then 'Commercial Units'
        when  [Location Type] != 'COMMER' and [Contract] = '2)FRA Components' then 'NOn Commercial Units' else [Component Description] end [Component Description]
```

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested if expression should do the trick.  I haven't had a chance to test it, but it should look something like this:

```
=IIF((Fields!Location_Type.Value = "COMMER") AND (Fields!Contract.Value = "2)FRA Components"), "Commercial Units", IIF((Fields!Location_Type.Value <> "COMMER") AND (Fields!Contract.Value = "2)FRA Components"), "Non Commercial", Fields!Component_Description.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks @SDC I'll give it a try

Answer (score 3):

SDC's answer should be good but my preference, especially when nesting a couple of `IIF`s is to use `SWITCH()` instead.

It looks more like a SQL `CASE` statement too. Then final `True` acts like an ELSE.

```
=SWITCH(
        Fields!Location_Type.Value = 'COMMER' and Fields!ContractValue = '2)FRA Components' , 'Commercial Units' ,
        Fields!Location_Type.Value <> 'COMMER' and Fields!ContractValue = '2)FRA Components' , 'Non Commercial Units' ,
        True, Fields!Component_Description.Value
)
```

The syntax is basically

```
=SWITCH(
    Test1, ReturnValue1,
    Test2, ReturnValue2,
    Test3, ReturnValue3,
    ....
    Test999, ReturnValue999
    )
```

SWITCH tests each condition and returns the first that evaluates to True.

So by setting the final expression evaluated to `True`, if all previous expressions return false then this one will return a value.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I went with your solution in the end.

Comment: OK great, can you mark at least one of the answers as accepted to help help others looking for similar answers.

Comment: Is it the up arrow that marks it as answered?

Comment: No, that's just the vote up button, just below the vote up/down buttons you should see a check mark... that accepts an answer